# Static variable inside PHP dynamic method

Tags: php, dynamic, methods, static

Why there are static variables inside dynamic methods in PHP? I supposed to use static to store value between method calls, but discovered that static vars are just like static fields (members) of class.

```
class A {
    public function B() {
        static $C;
        if (!isset($C) {
            $C = rand();
        }
        echo $C."\n";
    }
}

$i1 = new A;
$i1->B();

$i2 = new A;
$i2->B();
```

What is the best way to store value (cache it) between method's call?

Comment: Isn't that what happens? https://eval.in/141325

Answer (score 3):

A `static` variable is similar to a static member. One minor difference is that it's scoped to the function you've declared it in.

Keep in mind that static members have one other property: they are shared over all instances of a class. Sample code:

```
class A {
    function foo () {
        static $a = 0;
        $a += 1;
        var_dump($a);
    }
    function bar() {
        self::$a; // Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: A::$a
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo(); // 1
$a->foo(); // 2
$a2 = new A();
$a2->foo(); // 3!
```

This is problematic. My recommendation is: don't use static variables. Just have a private non-static member:

```
class A {
    private $a = 0;
    function foo () {
        $this->a += 1;
        var_dump($this->a);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo(); // 1
$a->foo(); // 2
$a2 = new A();
$a2->foo(); // 1
```

If you need to cache a value make that it's own entity:

```
$cache = new ValueProvider();
$a = new A($cache);
$a2 = new A($cache);
```

Now `A` doesn't need to know how `ValueProvider` get's the value, or even that it's cached. `$a` and `$a2` share their `ValueProvider`, but they don't know about that, and that's good.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've given, the variable `$C` maintains it's value between successive calls to function `B()`. It is also private to the function B(). Note, however, that it is truly `static` - every instance of `A` will have the same value of `$C` in it's method `B`.

The best way to store the value? That depends on what you're using it for:

1. If you need the value to be private to method `B` and you don't mind having the same value of `$C` for every instance of `A`, then this is the way to go.
2. If you need the value to be unique to every instance of `A`, then make it a (private) member variable (although in this case, it will be accessible from every method of `A`).